# jqGrid lose sort when paging

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jqGrid. A few of my settings are:

```
url: '/Operations.aspx/GetData',
datatype: 'json',
mtype: 'POST',
loadonce: true,
multiSort: true,
sortname: 'PrimerApellido asc, SegundoApellido asc, Nombre',
sortorder: 'asc',
jsonReader: {
    root: 'd.rows',
    page: 'd.page',
    total: 'd.total',
    records: 'd.records',
    id: 'Id',
    repeatitems: false
},
```

My colModel includes the columns Nombre, PrimerApellido and SegundoApellido (in this order, and with the same name and index: column Nombre has name 'Nombre' and index 'Nombre'). I set rowTotal in loadComplete with

```
$this.jqGrid('setGridParam', { rowTotal: $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') });
```

The grid shows the data correctly, but when I change the page, the data appears sorted by Nombre, PrimerApellido, SegundoApellido, and I can't sort by my settings :(
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Ok, it seems that it is a bug...  http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/multisort-column-priority/&value=change%20id&type=1&include=1&search=1&ret=all